# Google Cloud - Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "encoding" at 'config': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

When I try to invoke **Google Cloud Speech to Text Api** for long-running recognition with the following config:

```
config = dict(
            languageCode='de',
            maxAlternatives=1,
            enableWordTimeOffsets=True,
            enableAutomaticPunctuation=True,
            model='default',
            encoding='ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED'
          )
```

I get this error

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "encoding" at 'config': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list

How to fix it?

Comment: Hello Andrew. Would you please check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please give us some more information... like which language and library version you are using for this part of your project?

Assuming you are using **Python**, you could find another official way for connecting to **Google Cloud** Speech to Text **Api** here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics

The way I am used to do is by using `googleapiclient` phyton package alongside with JSON data structure instead of dictionary data.

```
import base64
import googleapiclient.discovery

with open(speech_file, 'rb') as speech:
    # Base64 encode the binary audio file for inclusion in the JSON
    # request.
    speech_content = base64.b64encode(speech.read())

# Construct the request
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('speech', 'v1')
service_request = service.speech().recognize(
    body={
        "config": {
            "encoding": "LINEAR16",  # raw 16-bit signed LE samples
            "sampleRateHertz": 16000,  # 16 khz
            "languageCode": "en-US",  # a BCP-47 language tag
        },
        "audio": {
            "content": speech_content
            }
        })
```

Refer to this official article if you don't know how to install python packages: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#id13

For LongRunning requests, please refer to:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/speech/longrunningrecognize

The config JSON structure in this case will be:

```
{
  "config": {
    object(RecognitionConfig)
  },
  "audio": {
    object(RecognitionAudio)
  }
}
```

Where **RecognitionConfig** is a JSON object of the kind:

```
{
  "encoding": enum(AudioEncoding),
  "sampleRateHertz": number,
  "languageCode": string,
  "maxAlternatives": number,
  "profanityFilter": boolean,
  "speechContexts": [
    {
      object(SpeechContext)
    }
  ],
  "enableWordTimeOffsets": boolean
}
```

And **RecognitionAudio** is of the kind:

```
{
  // Union field audio_source can be only one of the following:
  "content": string,
  "uri": string
  // End of list of possible types for union field audio_source.
}
```

For LongRunning recognition, you may also refer to this link:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/speech/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/speech/v1/Speech.SpeechOperations.html

It shows how to use the Phyton package `googleapiclient.discovery` for long running requests, which is just by using the following method in your Phyton class:

```
...
service_request = service.speech().longrunningrecognize(
        body= {
            "config": {
                "encoding": "FLAC",
                "languageCode": "en-US",
                "enableWordTimeOffsets": True
            },
            "audio": {
                "uri": str('gs://speech-clips/'+self.audio_fqid)
            }
        }
    )
...
```